# ChefZero returning 404

Tags: vagrant, chef-solo

I am setting up a simple vagrant box with chef solo as the provisioner. Everything was going fine until i tried running it on my laptop. The machine comes up fine but when it provisions it spits out some errors.

I'm relatively fresh to chef and i'm not quite sure what i'm looking at.
Any help is immensely appreciated.

**Error**

```
==> default: [2016-05-20T00:27:27+00:00] INFO: GET /organizations/chef/nodes/vagrant-ebebf4d0
==> default: [2016-05-20T00:27:27+00:00] INFO: #<ChefZero::RestErrorResponse: 404: Object not found: chefzero://localhost:8889/nodes/vagrant-ebebf4d0>
```

**Full Stack Trace**

```
    default: /tmp/vagrant-chef/fc2e73022d67a62fdf8d4974c11d0294/cookbooks => C:/Projects/new-vagrant/provision/cookbooks
==> default: Running provisioner: chef_solo...
    default: Installing Chef (latest)...
==> default: Generating chef JSON and uploading...
==> default: Running chef-solo...
==> default: stdin: is not a tty
==> default: [2016-05-20T00:27:25+00:00] INFO: Started chef-zero at chefzero://localhost:8889 with repository at /tmp/vagrant-chef/fc2e73022d67a62fdf8d4974c11d0294
==> default:   One version per cookbook
==> default: [2016-05-20T00:27:25+00:00] INFO: Forking chef instance to converge...
==> default: Starting Chef Client, version 12.11.1
==> default: [2016-05-20T00:27:25+00:00] INFO: *** Chef 12.11.1 ***
==> default: [2016-05-20T00:27:25+00:00] INFO: Platform: x86_64-linux
==> default: [2016-05-20T00:27:25+00:00] INFO: Chef-client pid: 2613
==> default: [2016-05-20T00:27:27+00:00] INFO: GET /organizations/chef/nodes/vagrant-ebebf4d0
==> default: [2016-05-20T00:27:27+00:00] INFO: #<ChefZero::RestErrorResponse: 404: Object not found: chefzero://localhost:8889/nodes/vagrant-ebebf4d0>
==> default: /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/chef-zero-4.6.2/lib/chef_zero/rest_base.rb:91:in `rescue in get_data'
==> default: /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/chef-zero-4.6.2/lib/chef_zero/rest_base.rb:83:in `get_data'
==> default: /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/chef-zero-4.6.2/lib/chef_zero/endpoints/rest_object_endpoint.rb:18:in `get'
==> default: /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/chef-zero-4.6.2/lib/chef_zero/rest_base.rb:62:in `call'
==> default: /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/chef-zero-4.6.2/lib/chef_zero/rest_router.rb:24:in `call'
==> default: /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/chef-zero-4.6.2/lib/chef_zero/server.rb:664:in `block in app'
==> default: /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/chef-zero-4.6.2/lib/chef_zero/server.rb:336:in `call'
==> default: /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/chef-zero-4.6.2/lib/chef_zero/server.rb:336:in `handle_socketless_request'
==> default: /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/chef-zero-4.6.2/lib/chef_zero/socketless_server_map.rb:87:in `request'
==> default: /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/chef-zero-4.6.2/lib/chef_zero/socketless_server_map.rb:33:in `request'
==> default: /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/chef-12.11.1/lib/chef/http/socketless_chef_zero_client.rb:154:in `request'
==> default: /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/chef-12.11.1/lib/chef/http.rb:305:in `block in send_http_request'
==> default: /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/chef-12.11.1/lib/chef/http.rb:336:in `block in retrying_http_errors'
==> default: /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/chef-12.11.1/lib/chef/http.rb:334:in `loop'
==> default: /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/chef-12.11.1/lib/chef/http.rb:334:in `retrying_http_errors'
==> default: /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/chef-12.11.1/lib/chef/http.rb:299:in `send_http_request'
==> default: /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/chef-12.11.1/lib/chef/http.rb:144:in `request'
==> default: /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/chef-12.11.1/lib/chef/http.rb:111:in `get'
==> default: /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/chef-12.11.1/lib/chef/node.rb:604:in `load'
==> default: /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/chef-12.11.1/lib/chef/node.rb:588:in `find_or_create'
==> default: /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/chef-12.11.1/lib/chef/policy_builder/dynamic.rb:72:in `load_node'
==> default: /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/chef-12.11.1/lib/chef/client.rb:465:in `load_node'
==> default: /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/chef-12.11.1/lib/chef/client.rb:267:in `run'
==> default: /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/chef-12.11.1/lib/chef/application.rb:285:in `block in fork_chef_client'
==> default: /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/chef-12.11.1/lib/chef/application.rb:273:in `fork'
==> default: /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/chef-12.11.1/lib/chef/application.rb:273:in `fork_chef_client'
==> default: /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/chef-12.11.1/lib/chef/application.rb:238:in `block in run_chef_client'
==> default: /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/chef-12.11.1/lib/chef/local_mode.rb:44:in `with_server_connectivity'
==> default: /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/chef-12.11.1/lib/chef/application.rb:226:in `run_chef_client'
==> default: /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/chef-12.11.1/lib/chef/application/client.rb:456:in `sleep_then_run_chef_client'
==> default: /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/chef-12.11.1/lib/chef/application/client.rb:443:in `block in interval_run_chef_client'
==> default: /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/chef-12.11.1/lib/chef/application/client.rb:442:in `loop'
==> default: /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/chef-12.11.1/lib/chef/application/client.rb:442:in `interval_run_chef_client'
==> default: /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/chef-12.11.1/lib/chef/application/client.rb:426:in `run_application'
==> default: /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/chef-12.11.1/lib/chef/application.rb:58:in `run'
==> default: /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/chef-12.11.1/lib/chef/application/solo.rb:216:in `run'
==> default: /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/chef-12.11.1/bin/chef-solo:25:in `<top (required)>'
==> default: /usr/bin/chef-solo:52:in `load'
==> default: /usr/bin/chef-solo:52:in `<main>'
==> default: [2016-05-20T00:27:27+00:00] INFO: HTTP Request Returned 404 Not Found: Object not found: chefzero://localhost:8889/nodes/vagrant-ebebf4d0
==> default: [2016-05-20T00:27:27+00:00] INFO: POST /organizations/chef/nodes
==> default: --- POST BODY ---
==> default: {"name":"vagrant-ebebf4d0","chef_environment":"_default","json_class":"Chef::Node","automatic":{},"normal":{},"chef_type":"node","default":{},"override":{},"run_list":[]}
==> default: --- END POST BODY ---
==> default: [2016-05-20T00:27:27+00:00] INFO: #<ChefZero::RestErrorResponse: 404: Parent not found: chefzero://localhost:8889/nodes>
==> default: /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/chef-zero-4.6.2/lib/chef_zero/rest_base.rb:187:in `rescue in create_data'
==> default: /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/chef-zero-4.6.2/lib/chef_zero/rest_base.rb:181:in `create_data'
==> default: /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/chef-zero-4.6.2/lib/chef_zero/endpoints/rest_list_endpoint.rb:31:in `post'
==> default: /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/chef-zero-4.6.2/lib/chef_zero/endpoints/nodes_endpoint.rb:24:in `post'
==> default: /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/chef-zero-4.6.2/lib/chef_zero/rest_base.rb:62:in `call'
==> default: /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/chef-zero-4.6.2/lib/chef_zero/rest_router.rb:24:in `call'
==> default: /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/chef-zero-4.6.2/lib/chef_zero/server.rb:664:in `block in app'
==> default: /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/chef-zero-4.6.2/lib/chef_zero/server.rb:336:in `call'
==> default: /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/chef-zero-4.6.2/lib/chef_zero/server.rb:336:in `handle_socketless_request'
==> default: /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/chef-zero-4.6.2/lib/chef_zero/socketless_server_map.rb:87:in `request'
==> default: /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/chef-zero-4.6.2/lib/chef_zero/socketless_server_map.rb:33:in `request'
==> default: /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/chef-12.11.1/lib/chef/http/socketless_chef_zero_client.rb:154:in `request'
==> default: /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/chef-12.11.1/lib/chef/http.rb:305:in `block in send_http_request'
==> default: /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/chef-12.11.1/lib/chef/http.rb:336:in `block in retrying_http_errors'
==> default: /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/chef-12.11.1/lib/chef/http.rb:334:in `loop'
==> default: /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/chef-12.11.1/lib/chef/http.rb:334:in `retrying_http_errors'
==> default: /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/chef-12.11.1/lib/chef/http.rb:299:in `send_http_request'
==> default: /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/chef-12.11.1/lib/chef/http.rb:144:in `request'
==> default: /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/chef-12.11.1/lib/chef/http.rb:127:in `post'
==> default: /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/chef-12.11.1/lib/chef/node.rb:639:in `create'
==> default: /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/chef-12.11.1/lib/chef/node.rb:592:in `rescue in find_or_create'
==> default: /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/chef-12.11.1/lib/chef/node.rb:588:in `find_or_create'
==> default: /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/chef-12.11.1/lib/chef/policy_builder/dynamic.rb:72:in `load_node'
==> default: /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/chef-12.11.1/lib/chef/client.rb:465:in `load_node'
==> default: /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/chef-12.11.1/lib/chef/client.rb:267:in `run'
==> default: /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/chef-12.11.1/lib/chef/application.rb:285:in `block in fork_chef_client'
==> default: /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/chef-12.11.1/lib/chef/application.rb:273:in `fork'
==> default: /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/chef-12.11.1/lib/chef/application.rb:273:in `fork_chef_client'
==> default: /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/chef-12.11.1/lib/chef/application.rb:238:in `block in run_chef_client'
==> default: /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/chef-12.11.1/lib/chef/local_mode.rb:44:in `with_server_connectivity'
==> default: /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/chef-12.11.1/lib/chef/application.rb:226:in `run_chef_client'
==> default: /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/chef-12.11.1/lib/chef/application/client.rb:456:in `sleep_then_run_chef_client'
==> default: /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/chef-12.11.1/lib/chef/application/client.rb:443:in `block in interval_run_chef_client'
==> default: /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/chef-12.11.1/lib/chef/application/client.rb:442:in `loop'
==> default: /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/chef-12.11.1/lib/chef/application/client.rb:442:in `interval_run_chef_client'
==> default: /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/chef-12.11.1/lib/chef/application/client.rb:426:in `run_application'
==> default: /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/chef-12.11.1/lib/chef/application.rb:58:in `run'
==> default: /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/chef-12.11.1/lib/chef/application/solo.rb:216:in `run'
==> default: /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/chef-12.11.1/bin/chef-solo:25:in `<top (required)>'
==> default: /usr/bin/chef-solo:52:in `load'
==> default: /usr/bin/chef-solo:52:in `<main>'
==> default: [2016-05-20T00:27:27+00:00] INFO: HTTP Request Returned 404 Not Found: Parent not found: chefzero://localhost:8889/nodes
==> default: ================================================================================
==> default: Chef encountered an error attempting to load the node data for "vagrant-ebebf4d0"
==> default: ================================================================================
==> default: Resource Not Found:
==> default: -------------------
==> default: The server returned a HTTP 404. This usually indicates that your chef_server_url is incorrect.
==> default: Relevant Config Settings:
==> default: -------------------------
==> default: chef_server_url "chefzero://localhost:8889"
==> default: Platform:
==> default: ---------
==> default: x86_64-linux
==> default: Running handlers:
==> default: [2016-05-20T00:27:27+00:00] ERROR: Running exception handlers
==> default: Running handlers complete
==> default: [2016-05-20T00:27:27+00:00] ERROR: Exception handlers complete
==> default: Chef Client failed. 0 resources updated in 02 seconds
==> default: [2016-05-20T00:27:27+00:00] FATAL: Stacktrace dumped to /var/chef/cache/chef-stacktrace.out
==> default: [2016-05-20T00:27:27+00:00] FATAL: Please provide the contents of the stacktrace.out file if you file a bug report
==> default: [2016-05-20T00:27:27+00:00] ERROR: 404 "Not Found"
==> default: [2016-05-20T00:27:29+00:00] FATAL: Chef::Exceptions::ChildConvergeError: Chef run process exited unsuccessfully (exit code 1)
Chef never successfully completed! Any errors should be visible in the
output above. Please fix your recipes so that they properly complete.
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I believe this is related to [this issue](https://github.com/chef/chef/issues/4948) in Chef core.

The fix seems to be to add the following to your chef_solo provisioner section in your Vagrantfile:

```
chef.version = '12.10.40'
```

Answer (score 6):

I had to set both version and channel in my Vagrantfile:

```
chef.channel = "stable"
chef.version = "12.10.24"
```

This way vagrant uses the good url to download old chef stable version.

Answer (score 2):

I seem to have found the answer. I'll post it here in case anyone else is experiencing this issue

This a bug in the current "latest" build of chef when using vagrant.

https://github.com/chef/chef/issues/4948

The last comment on the issue solves the error.

Comment: The last comment explicitly *doesn't* explain how to solve the issue (maybe because there've been comments since) but https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/provisioning/chef_common.html implies you do so by adding `chef.channel = "stable"` to the `Vagrantfile`. However, you might need to destroy entirely and re-provision. `chef.version= "..."` might also work, with explicit version numbers as mentioned on that thread.